# cmake and make build reproductibility

Tags: c, makefile, cmake, embedded

I'm evaluating the use of cmake to generate makefile for embedded FW. The `cmakelists.txt` will be shared in the team.

1. Can you confirm the makefile cannot be shared between different computers ?
2. Is this still true if project path is identical on both computers ?
3. **Using cmake makefile generation and same version of compiler, will the generated binary be the same on all computers ?**
4. Is this the same behavior as a makefile shared in the project ?

Comment: As @MultipleMonomials has already mentioned: this is really, really bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you share a generated makefile anyway!? You usually share the cmake files.

> 1. Can you confirm the makefile cannot be shared between different computers ?

You ***should not*** **share the makefile**. It's generated only for you and includes local information as well as the cmake (cached) options and state. There's no serious reason to actually do this!

> 2. Is this still true if project path is identical on both computers ?

Yes, because **cmake maintains a cache of settings, options etc**. So the makefile may differ depending on paths, options and states. You also have to guarantee the paths for any dependency.

> 3. Using cmake makefile generation and same version of compiler, will the generated binary be the same on all computers ?

If environment (Compiler, libraries, …) and options (build type, project options, …) are same, Cmake will ***reliable produce exact the same binaries*** on all systems.

> 4. Is this the same behavior as a makefile shared in the project ?

No, CMake is much better: it's cross-platform. It doesn't depend on *make*, you can use any other system (like ninja or an IDE project) too – without touching your source or cmake code.

CMake does much more than just creating a makefile. You can even compile a CMake based project with several different compiler / cross-compiler without a single change.

#### TL;DR

***Don't share generated Makfiles***, share the Cmake sourcefiles instead – that's what CMake is used for.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, if your project path, toolchain path, toolchain version, and the path to every external library used by the project is the same on different computers, then you can move the generated Makefile between them without regenerating.  When you run `make` it might detect that things have changed and try to rerun CMake, though.  I'm not sure why you'd want to do this, however, it seems like kind of bad practice.

If the compilers, libraries, and code are the same, the same code will get generated (unless your compiler has some sort of bug).

Comment: I reformulate to be very precise. cmake will generate different makefiles on different computers (because of path). Will the final binary be different ?

Comment: As long as the entire toolchain is the same, and there are no absolute paths encoded into the binary, then the final binaries should be the same.